# directoryperdb issue

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB to run as a Windows Service on Win 7 and everything runs well. However, when I attempt to use the command --directoryperdb, it does not recognize this command.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this still a problem? I've been using mongo on Windows with or without this switch, and its not been a problem.

Also, as of 1.6.0, logging works when mongo is run as a windows service. Therefore, you will have an error message to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues which come to mind that may or may not help you:

- Are you using 1.3.2 or later?

  > `--directoryperdb`
  >   Specify use of an alternative directory structure, in which files for each database are kept in a unique directory. (since 1.3.2)

  [Source](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters)
- Does it work without this argument as a service, and/or with the argument whilst not running as a service? Have you checked permissions for the user the service is running under?
- Are you/have you tried running the same thing but by specifying the arguments [using a config file](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration) instead?